# adding values of dynamic textbox in php

Tags: php, dynamic, textbox, addition

i have this code of displaying name textbox and price of the product

```
$que = "SELECT * FROM additionals";
$res = mysql_query($que, $con);
   if(mysql_num_rows($res)>0){
     while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){ ?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $row['name'] ?> :</td><td><input type="text" name="
<?php echo $row['name']; ?>"  /></td><td>* <?php echo $row['price'];?></td>
</tr>
```

now i need to store and add all their values example textbox1=1 textbox2=2 $result=3
i need to store them dynamically and them add them can anybody help me

Comment: Your question is not clear

Comment: I don't understand the question. Are you trying to update existing records in the DB? Could you provide some code samples of what you have tried so far?

Comment: thank you for answering here is the print screen of it to completly enlighten you http://prntscr.com/to5xi i want that if you press next it will multiply to the price and add it to the next row

Answer (score 1):

i think you might want this

```
$que = "SELECT * FROM additionals";
$res = mysql_query($que, $con);
   if(mysql_num_rows($res)>0){
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){ ?>
<tr>
<td><?php echo $row['name'] ?> :</td><td><input type="text" name="
<?php echo $row['name']; ?>" value="<?php echo $row['price'];?" /></td>
</tr>
<?php }?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to add values of each row's price then all you need is a sub_total variable, like this:

```
<?php
$que = "SELECT * FROM additionals";
$res = mysql_query($que, $con);
$output = '<table>';
$sub_total = 0;

if(mysql_num_rows($res) > 0){
    while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)){
        $sub_total += $row['price'];

        $output .= '<tr>';
        $output .= '<td>'.$row['name'].'</td><td><input type="text" name="';
        $output .= $row['name'].'"  /></td><td>* '.$row['price'].'</td>';
        $output .= '</tr>';
    }
}

$output .= '</table>';
echo $output;
?>
```

I'm not sure where you want to write those textbox1,2,3,etc. out, please note in the comment section of this answer and I'll update the answer to your needs.

Comment: thank you for answering sir here is the print screen of it to completly enlighten you http://prntscr.com/to5xi i want that if you press next it will multiply to the price and add it to the next row

Comment: Glad to be able to help :). You can do that in two ways. Live with JavaScript (jQuery) or by sending GET/POST to the same PHP file. It also depends on if you "care" about security. You can use all 3 methods, but always have to valide what data you are getting back from the forms. If you "think" you have limited a field to a max value (for example 10) it's easy for the user to adjust those values manually and send them to your script. Always check the values you are getting back in your script before doing something with them (writing to DB-systems or changing content based on it).

Answer (score 0):

You could try the following:

```
<?php echo $row['name']; ?> : <input type="text" name="data[<?php echo $row['id']; ?>]" value="<?php echo $row['price'];?>"  />
```

then on post processing

```
$data=$_POST['data'];
while(list($key,$value)=each($data))
{
    $sql="UPDATE additionals SET price='".mysql_escape_string($value)."' WHERE id=".intval($key);
    mysql_query($sql, $con);
}
```

This assumes that your tables index is 'id' and its an integer.
Using it as part of the input allows you access to the index and the value as a pair.